# C# combine to list in json object

Tags: c#, json

I have two lists of string:

```
        List<string> tmpCols = new List<string>();
        List<string> tmpRows = new List<string>();
```

e.g. tmpCols = [A,B,C]; and tmpRows = [X, Y];

I need to iterate both list and get a Json result like this:

```
        new matrix() { id = "1", col = "A", row = "X" });
        new matrix() { id = "2", col = "B", row = "X" });
        new matrix() { id = "3", col = "C", row = "X" });
        new matrix() { id = "4", col = "A", row = "Y" });
        new matrix() { id = "5", col = "B", row = "Y" });
        new matrix() { id = "6", col = "C", row = "Y" });
```

The dimension in this case would be 2 rows and 3 columns.

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve your problem? Is there any code?

Comment: I have tried use two basic for loop but with no success.

Comment: Please post the code from your attempt. Maybe people can help you to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a textbook example of a nested loop.  Loops can contain other loops, where the inner one repeats for each element of the outer one.  This one might look something like:

```
var result = new List<matrix>();
var count = 1;
foreach (var r in tmpRows)
    foreach (var c in tmpCols)
        result.Add(new matrix { id = (count++).ToString(), col = c, row = r });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a late answer

> need to iterate both list and get a Json result like this:

It is not a json, I guess you want something like this

```
List<string> tmpCols = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
List<string> tmpRows = new List<string>() { "X", "Y" };

var query = tmpCols.SelectMany(c => tmpRows.Select(r => new {id=index++, col=c, row = r }));
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 6,
    "col": "A",
    "row": "X"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "col": "A",
    "row": "Y"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "col": "B",
    "row": "X"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "col": "B",
    "row": "Y"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "col": "C",
    "row": "X"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "col": "C",
    "row": "Y"
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved using this code:

```
        var tmpMatrix = new List<matrix>();

        for (int k = 0; k < tmpRows.Count; k++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < tmpCols.Count; j++)
            {
                int ident = k*tmpCols.Count + j;
                tmpMatrix.Add(new matrix() { id = ident.ToString(), col = tmpCols[j], row = tmpRows[k] });
            }

        }
```

Comment: Nothing related with json.

Comment: @EZI That's because the question has nothing to do with JSON